# React InstantSearch RefinementList transformItems not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algolia, react-instantsearch

So I have successfully implemented the React InstantSearch library in my app, and am trying to apply a filter to the refinement list (to ensure the filters that show up are relevant to the active user, and hide the ones that aren't). I have tried the below:

```
<RefinementList attributeName="organization" transformItems={items => items.filter(e => refineList.indexOf(e)>=0)} />
```

where **refineList** is a simple array of strings (i.e. ["A", "B", "C"])

However the RefinementList keeps showing all of the filter options, without having the "transformItems" function applied to it. Would it be that I had misunderstood how the "transformItems" works?

Documentation was quite sparse on this topic, so I'm sure it'd be helpful for many other users of the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `transformItems` function has one parameter: `items`. It expects in return to have it back.

`items` is an array of objects with the following shape:

```
{
  label: string,
  value: array<string>,
  count: number,
  isRefined: bool,
}
```

To remove a refinement based on an array of strings you can do this:

```
const refineList = ['A', 'B'];
<RefinementList
    attributeName="organization"
    transformItems={items => items.filter(e => 
        refineList.indexOf(e.label) >= 0)}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! It worked perfectly :) Should've known it was me misinterpreting the format of the "items" array.